# glTFLoader vs ObjLoader in threejs?

Tags: javascript, three.js, gltf

I've always used .obj files to load models into three.js. 
I read somewhere that the preferred approach is to now use .gltf.

As I've begun to do so, I'm realizing that while loading in an object does seem simple with gltf, obj seems to be more flexible once the object is inside.

Things like:

- Changing material properties
- Changing the shading to flat
- Controlling how the object reacts to specific inputs.

These all appear to be difficult / not supported in gltf where you can do them easily with obj.

What specifically is the benefit to gltf? I'm assuming file size but seems like you have to give up a lot of control for that benefit.

Comment: You can control all of the things above with any format – once you load the model into threejs it's just a THREE.Scene or THREE.Mesh. The difference might be that OBJ was giving you one single Mesh, where the glTF file might have multiple nested objects in a Scene? That depends on the model, but can require slightly different code to manage.

Comment: okay this makes sense; if there are multiple meshes then how do i query them? 

more explanation: I've built my model with like 80 different objects; i could merge them down but multi-materials in .glb aren't supported i think so i could probably only merge down to liek 12 separate meshes.
EDIT: found a tutorial here: https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-load-gltf.html
looks like there's no easy way but you can log out the heirarchy in the console and as i've built my own model i should be able to re-export with proper layer names and then be able to access. Thanks @don

Comment: [`object.traverse((o) => {...})`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.traverse) or [`.getObjectByName(name)`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.getObjectByName) are the most common ways to work with a nested object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no advantage that I can think of of .obj vs gltf. Obj doesn't easily support hierarchies .. it doesn't support modern materials, no shaders, no lights/cameras.. no geometry groups. Obj is basically a terrible format except that it is human readable, (which text gltf is also). Additionally.. gltf supports mesh compression... Compressed texture format . Binary buffers, single file export with embedded resources. Obj format is from the late 70s iircs. Gltf is the product of 4 more decades of progress in real-time 3d and is designed from the ground up for web 3d asset delivery.

Comment: any reference providing support to your answer?